# System.Diagnostics.Process.is always true, when no default program is registered

Tags: c#, xml, windows, process

How to repro:

1. Delete the key and subkey `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.xml`
2. Create a XML `%temp%\myxml.xml`
3. and run this c#

   ```
   System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("%temp%\myxml.xml");
   if (process == null)
   {
       log.WriteError("Failed to Launch a XML Editor. ");
       return;
   }

   //Wait for the Editor to be closed.
   while (!process.HasExited); //<= This line is always true
   ```

How to HasExited to be waiting when the user is still using the file/program ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here? Are you saying that `HasExited` is returning true when the program is open? Are you saying that there is no `process` that is started, but that line returns true anyway? What happens when you run this program? I'm guessing Internet Explorer opens...

Comment: Seems a bit dangerous to suggest we delete keys in our registry!

Comment: I found the issue here. If i have a default editor as notepad++  [launched in UAC non admin mode]. Then i run my program it launches another tab and opens my XML file. But the launcher [my program] thinks the notepadd ++ exits already. If i have notepadd++ launched in administrator mode, no issues. All works as expected, (i mean process.HasExcited is working as expected.) So i added a app.manifest with <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> so my program is enforced to launch always as administrator.